# Angular 9 - Child Routes of Lazy Laoded Module are not working (cannot match any routes)

Tags: angular

im trying to implement lazy loading for my backend of the app. Now it tells me there are no such routes.

My AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: StartPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'schulungen/:name',
    component: StartPageComponent,
  },
  {
    // ToDo: AuthGuard
    path: 'hdv',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/hdv-page/hdv-page.module').then(m => m.HdvPageModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

My HdvRoutingModule

```
const hdvRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HdvPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full', children: [
      {path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'bookings', component: RegistrationsComponent},
      {path: 'bookings/:id', component: SingleRegistrationComponent},
      {path: 'dimensions', component: EventsComponent},
      {path: 'dimensions/create', component: CreateEventComponent},
      {path: 'dimensions/edit/:id', component: EditEventComponent},
      {path: 'dimensions/:id', component: SingleEventComponent},
      {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(hdvRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HdvRoutingModule {
}
```

When I go to the route /hdv The `HdvPageComponent` loads correctly with the `Dashboardcomponent` in the  of HdvPageComponent like I would it expect to do. But when I go to `/hdv/bookings` I get the error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'hdv/bookings'`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having conflicts using the pathMatch in your `HdvRoutingModule`. You only need to remove that property.

I write some code and you can see the solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hj7ll).

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HdvPageComponent } from './hdv-page/hdv-page.component';
import { RegistrationsComponent } from './registrations/registrations.component';

const hdvRoutes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '', 
  component: HdvPageComponent,
  children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'bookings',
        component: RegistrationsComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(hdvRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HdvRoutingModule {
}
```

`hdv-page.component.html`

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- outer outlet in hdv-page component to see its children -->
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Can you explain why pathMatch 'full' did not work? I thought it would make sense since `''` will always match to any route or not ?